# Enum hex value to textbloc text

Tags: wpf, font-awesome

I found a large enum of the FontAwesome library and I'm wanting to use this in my WPF application for icons/images in Textblocks. The enum looks like the following:

```
public enum Type
{
    ...
    //ExclamationCircle, 0xf06A
    ExclamationCircle = 0xf06A,
    //ExclamationTriangle, 0xf071
    ExclamationTriangle = 0xf071,
    //Expand, 0xf065
    Expand = 0xf065,
    ...
}
```

I'd like to use this enum to set the value of my Textblock so I don't have to use the HEX value beside it (0xf071 for example). In my XAML, I have the following that works how I want:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tbIcon" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" Text="&#xf071;" Foreground="{StaticResource RedBrush}" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" />
```

[image: binding image]

When I add the following code, I no longer get the image but the actual text I've entered.

```
 public DialogBase(string title, string message, Window owner)
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     tbIcon.Text = FontAwesome.Type.ExclamationTriangle.AsHexString();
 }

 public static string AsHexString(this FontAwesome.Type type)
 {
     return String.Format(@"\u{0}", ((int)type).ToString("X").ToLower());
     // This is returning "\uf071"
 }
```

[image: incorrect image]

In the long run, I want to make this a public property of a new control so it can be bound but I'm wanting to get this step working first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change **u** to **x**:

```
public static string AsHexString(this FontAwesome.Type type)
{
    return String.Format(@"\x{0}", ((int)type).ToString("X").ToLower());
    // This is returning "\xf071"
}
```

You may also want to try to set the `FontFamily` like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tbIcon" TextElement.FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/FontAwesome.WPF;component/#FontAwesome" Foreground="{StaticResource RedBrush}" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" />
```

It works for me :)